# Is there a way to group favorited questions or search among them per topic?

Tags: feature-request, support, questions, bookmarks

On Stack Overflow, after you star (or favorite) many questions, it becomes difficult to search among them to find an old question you starred.

Is there a way to search among them per topic? Would not it be useful to being able to group or search among them for example by the topic?

Comment: I understand the preposition tag correction, but favourite is the British spelling: it was correct wasn't it?

Comment: Either spelling is fine; that shouldn't have been changed.  If you want, you can edit it back to the previous spelling.

Comment: `infavorites:mine`

Comment: Some of us Americans use automated spell checkers which flag certain words spelled correctly in British English as incorrectly spelled, and thus when we fix all the spelling errors, those get "fixed" too. You can reinstate the British spelling if you want it, but I don't normally revert edits that change those spellings provided they perform some other non-localized edits.

Comment: It did not provide any additional information correcting it and it will not reverting it back.